# Best practises to store refresh token in cookie

Tags: angular, cookies, token, session-cookies, refresh-token

I have a refresh token and access token in my cookies. The refresh token refreshes the acces token.

1. With what flags is it best to set both cookies? From what I have seen on most sites cookies are set as sameSite=none secure=true. Is this a good practice?
2. Is it possible to remove refreshToken from all requests? I don't want it flying around in requests. I only need it in one POST request(in body) to refresh accessesToken. Maybe cookies are not the best place to store refreshToken?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to not store cookies in the cookie/browser at all and instead use the BFF pattern as described in these videos:

- [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2618s)
- [Using the BFF pattern to secure SPA and Blazor Applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc&t=163s)

If you still want to store them in the cookies, then they should definitively use the samesite=none, secure, HttpOnly.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)